# Failed to download repository information 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, repository

Every time I check for updates, I get:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http ://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http ://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.31.202.63 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Some other suggestions are to look in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but there is nothing about cz in that file, nor does it contain "ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/..." mentioned is another answer on this forum.  This has been going on for a while and I hoped that some mirror list might be fixed and the problem might go away, but I finally feel it's worth mentioning.  Usually, I just get a warning, and updates still happen, but I had an issue trying to load a package today and I'm wondering if they may be connected.

I've been using ubuntu for several years, so I'm not a complete noob, but this is outside my knowledge area, and I haven't been able to google an answer.

Note: I added a space after two of the link : because my reputation is too low to post more that two links.

uname -a

```
Linux transition 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:50:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This problem is not a duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) because my problem is not with ppa, and none of the solutions there fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your`/etc/apt/sources.list` does not contain this server (or lines that refer to `saucy`) you may have to remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` - it is possible that there are remains of an older version. try this:

```
$ sudo rm -i /var/lib/apt/lists/cz.*
$ sudo apt-get update
```

it is also possible that there is something referring to this server in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. if so: delete the file and `$ sudo apt-get update`.

make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` refers to the correct ubuntu version. you can find out what release you are running with

```
$ lsb_release -av
```

your `sources.list` file should only contain entries that have the `Codename` that is listed in the command above.

but if you still run `saucy`: it has reached it's [end-of-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29). you will still find it in the [old-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/).

you need to change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse
```

and so on.

you may consider upgrading to a newer - still supported - version of ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed, /var/lib/apt/lists/ did have several files prefixed cz.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_ and I removed them.  I just checked for updates, and no warnings or errors so far.  I'll do a little more testing, after at least one reboot, before declaring success.

Comment: I have also confirmed that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` only contains references to trusty.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me.  Thanks.

Comment: also in my case in "software & updates" under "Other software"  there was a checked line for "Ubuntu 13.10 'Saucy Salamander'. Removing that resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have some lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that refer to `saucy` release that is not supported any more.

Just remove them. If you have Ubuntu 14.04, you need only `trusty` repositories.

Comment: There is no "saucy" in my /etc/apt/sources.list.  I see another answer mentioning /var/lib/apt/lists/ and, indeed, there are some files beginning with cz.